# Flask Custom Login and Template Rendering

Tags: python, authentication, model-view-controller, flask, flask-login

I am new to learning Python for web development and have decided to go with Flask as my framework of choice as of now. I have chosen this primarily for its bare-bones approach on web development and I want to make as much of my web app custom and on my own as possible. I have made a very basic MVC framework in PHP and would like to make something like this in Python. I was researching some ways to interact with a database and add user login/register support and my original thoughts were that I wanted to do this all custom with my own methods and objects and what not. Similar to how I have done in PHP, so I can learn as much about developing my own back-end efficiently for long term production projects. In some research I found the basic objects in Flask such as `Login Manager`, `Login-Form` and `Flask-Admin`, etc. I don't like the idea of using these nicely packaged things that I have very little control over and have not dev'd custom.

Using that kind of stuff I also feel that I am not learning how all of that stuff works on the lowest level so I could not reproduce some of the benefits they are giving me later on in life when project circumstances change and maximum flexibility, customization, maintainability, and efficiency is needed. Obviously I am not in that position right now, but I `DO` know how to write this back end stuff in PHP and am just wondering if that means anything as far as managing sessions and Authentication on my own in Python/Flask, or if my thinking is totally out of ocontext and its not even close to managing the same stuff.

Comment: i advise you to use flask-login

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a really great idea to learn how authentication works at a low level -- it's particularly important as many people never learn this stuff, and it's quite interesting!

What I'd recommend you do is take a look at the official Flask tutorial (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/), as it covers a lot of this (working directly with sessions, etc.).

What I would *not* recommend, however, is using this sort of thing in production.

Using your own authentication code is almost never a good idea -- it's much better to rely on a well supported library that has been audited by other people for security issues.

In the Flask world you've got a couple choices:

- Flask-Login: https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
- Flask-Security: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/
- Flask-Stormpath: http://flask-stormpath.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Of those 3, I really like Flask-Stormpath -- but I'm super biased as I wrote it =)

Flask-Stormpath supports the widest array of customization / etc., and allows you to do whatever you want with it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Excellent response thank you. As far as the "choices" that I have (Flask-Login, Flask-Security, Flask-Stormpath), are these options/choices I have, technically just plugins or objects that I can import and install to my existing project? And if so, at some point I imagine with enough experience/expertise one could develop a very basic authentication framework and build on it as well as throw it on a resume and to show experience...

Comment: Those are all plugins you can use to add auth into your Flask app -- they are listed in terms of functionality (Flask-Login is the simplest, and the best to build on top of if you want a bare-bones experience).

Answer (score 0):

Flask official doc have some app examples. One of them is [MiniTwit](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tree/master/examples/minitwit/) a micro Twitter clone. As it is a complete app, you could found much of what you're looking for. If you want to make something greater, try [Full Stack Python Flask](http://www.fullstackpython.com/flask.html) tutorial